# Geolocation not working on Chrome even from a host server

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I was working on a html5 file which uses geolocation. It was working fine in Chrome version 38.0.2125.111m from both loading the file locally and from a host server. Now, Chrome does not work for geolocation from either resource. I understand the security issue when running the file locally, but it still happens from any website that is running geolocation. I get the error message of "geocode service failed". BUT runs fine from both resources using Firefox. I have a windows 7 x64 laptop. The code that I am using is right off of Google geolocation example...

I've also went to the chrome's privacy-security-location settings and checked to use allow all sites to check location and still the problem continues... Help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a clue. I copied the geolocaton file to another website and ran fine using the same chrome version which makes me believe that it is the google api keys that was causing the problem. I deleted the keys for both local and web host and will see in a few days if indeed this was the case. If it is, then I suggest not to establish api keys during development until app is ready for production.